# How do I validate Array inputs in Laravel 5.0

Tags: arrays, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a table, where the user can fill in information. However, the user can add rows and/or delete rows. I used a cloning function for that.

My html looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TB1_a[]">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TB1_b[]">
```

As you can see, it is an array input. So if the user adds a row, I'll have two values stored in TB1_a[] and TB1_b. 
Now, I would like to make my rules so that if the user enters information inside TB1_a[0], I would like to make TB1_b[0] required, but valid if **both** TB1_a[0] and TB1_b[0] are empty.

My validation rules:

```
'TB1_a.*' => 'required_with:TB1_b.*',
'TB1_b.*' => 'required_with:TB1_a.*'
```

However, these rules are unable to detect that I am referring to an array, meaning Laravel does not detect the '.*'. I would also like to point out that this logic was working perfectly with Laravel 5.4, but I have had to downgrade my Laravel and now it stops working. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, this[`.*`] notation was introduced in Laravel 5.2+. So, to achieve the array validation, you would need to add custom rules. [Reference Link](https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/)

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',//add more static rules as you need
  ];

  foreach($this->request->get('TB1_a') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['TB1_a.'.$key] = 'required_with:TB1_b.'.$key;
  }

  foreach($this->request->get('TB1_b') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['TB1_b.'.$key] = 'required_with:TB1_a.'.$key;
  }

  /*
  To combine the both validation rules in 1 loop. considering number of both fields are always equal
      foreach($this->request->get('TB1_a') as $key => $val)
      {
        $rules['TB1_a.'.$key] = 'required_with:TB1_b.'.$key;
        $rules['TB1_b.'.$key] = 'required_with:TB1_a.'.$key;
      }  
  */
  return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, yea this makes much more sense. I felt Laravel 5.0 might have some other type of notation, but I guess not. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: So I tried to do what you suggested, but I'm running into another problem. If I leave both empty, and progress it works as expected (i.e. Valid). However, if I fill in both of them, it says that the data is invalid. I am super confused as to what is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong :(. Could you please try to print the values of `$rules` and post the op. just to check if rules are getting as we want them to.

Comment: Also, if you could add error message as given in reference link, that might help to see if which variable is failing (a or b)

Comment: Yea sure, I outputted $rules as well as all of the inputs I retrieve, just to make sure everything is working correct. My rules are: 
`$rules => [
'TB1_a.0' => 'required_with: TB1_b.0',
'TB1_b.0' => 'required_with:TB1_a.0',
'TB1_a.1' => 'required_with: TB1_b.1',
'TB1_b.1' => 'required_with: TB1_a.1'
]` and this is if I have two rows.

Comment: and my inputs are exactly as I expect them. Even records the null value, if I leave it empty.

Comment: I am so sorry! It works exactly like you said, I had just missed a `.` in one of my statements. Thanks for bearing with me!