# Retrieving data for potentially infinite user-added form fields in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, request, substring

I have a form where users can create posts containing a list of ingredients. A user can add **unlimited** new inputs with an incrementing name - 'ingredient-1', 'ingredient-2' and so on.

In my controller function I want to loop through the request and retrieve only the fields where the key starts with the substring 'ingredient-' then save these to my Ingredient model along with a reference to the post id.

What is the best way to achieve this in Laravel or PHP?

Comment: use array inputs. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45675161/4233593

Comment: is the input for ingredients a textbox? you can do multiple select, there are many beautiful libraries for that. and then retrieve the multiple select, it is an array